# Adding toolbar to GUI in JAVA

Tags: java, user-interface, jframe, containers

I am working on chess game. I have JFrame where I've container, which include 2d array of JLabel fields. Now i would like to add to my window a toolbar, but when i want to do that, my chessboard crumble. This is a picture how my window with chessboard look like [Window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/co1cb.jpg). I want to add toolbar on the top of the window, where i can for example save/load game ...etc
Also I would like to add to the right side some panel where i can see previous moves. I would like to know how to do that without destroying my chessboard.
Here is my code:

```
public class GUI extends JFrame implements Serializable{
 public void initGUI() {
    setTitle("Chess game");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
    ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon("pieceImages/whiteKing.png");
    contentPane = getContentPane();
    GridLayout gridLayout = new GridLayout(8, 8);
    contentPane.setLayout(gridLayout);
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
            labels[i][j]=new JLabel(game.getBoard()[i][j].getImagePath());
            contentPane.add(labels[i][j]);
        }
    }
    setIconImage(img.getImage());
    setResizable(false);
    setSize(600, 600);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setVisible(true);
}
```

I created suggestion of some JPanel how it would look like:

```
public class Toolbar extends JPanel implements Serializable {
   public Toolbar(){
       JButton newGameBtn = new JButton("New game");
       JButton regretBtn = new JButton("Regret move");
       add(newGameBtn);
       add(regretBtn);
   }
}
```

Comment: Can you include a complete SSCCE? You didn't show the code where you add the toolbar to your application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may set a `BorderLayout` to the content pane, add the toolbar to the north, and another panel holding the labels, to the center .

```
    setTitle("Chess game");
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
    ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon("pieceImages/whiteKing.png");
    contentPane = getContentPane();

    contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    Toolbar toolbar = new Toolbar();

    JPanel labelsPanel = new JPanel();

    GridLayout gridLayout = new GridLayout(8, 8);
    labelsPanel.setLayout(gridLayout);
    for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
            labels[i][j]=new JLabel(game.getBoard()[i][j].getImagePath());
            labelsPanel.add(labels[i][j]);
        }
    }

    contentPane.add(toolbar, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    contentPane.add(labelsPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);

    setIconImage(img.getImage());
    setResizable(false);
    setSize(600, 600);
    setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    setVisible(true);
```

Also note that you could use a [JToolBar](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JToolBar.html) , see [How to Use Tool Bars](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toolbar.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use two panels, one for the toolbar and the other panel as the main game panel.

So, in your GUI class, set the layout as BorderLayout and add the toolbar panel with the NORTH constraint and add the game panel with the CENTER constraint. Something like:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
            frame.setTitle("Chess game");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE);
            Container contentPane = frame.getContentPane();
            contentPane.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
            JPanel toolbar = new JPanel(); // stablish any layout...
            toolbar.add(new JButton("Save"));
            // add the rest of the buttons...

            JPanel game = new JPanel(); // this is your current contentPane
            GridLayout gridLayout = new GridLayout(8, 8);
            game.setLayout(gridLayout);
            game.add(new JButton("Any Component"));
            game.add(new JButton("Any other Component"));

            contentPane.add(toolbar, BorderLayout.NORTH);
            contentPane.add(game, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```